# How to use a large image with many tap points linked to unique pages?

Tags: swift, xcode, uistoryboard

I'm brand new to Xcode, and Swift, and relatively new to coding. My app is basically a standalone video game map, with no game attached. So, the main screen is a view of a map. To be clear: my app is just an index of pages containing photos and text with three screens–I'm not writing any kind of code that will interact with any GPS information, and the user can't input any information.

I figured I would make my map as a png, and then make icons that I could lay over the map. I was hoping that each icon could be assigned to recognize a tap, and then trigger the desired action. However, I cannot fathom how to accomplish this.

From my understanding, the UI recognizes the relative location of a tap based on the tap coordinates within a view, but the UI cannot recognize the location of a tap within an image that extends beyond the view.

I'm using UIscrollview to make my image scrollable, and I have a large graphic that extends well beyond the phone screen.

I feel like I could figure out a way to accomplish this, however I'm stuck on the display area in XCode. Since my image is way bigger than the phone screen I cant even see the whole image at once, and figure out how to possibly handle assigning all the gesture recognizers and links.

Any advice on tutorials, or anything else is really appreciated. I attached an image below that hopefully makes it more clear, as well as an image of my main map.

[image: My map]

[image: My dilemma]

Comment: @Mars What part of the question needs clarification? It's not very helpful to suggest that I clarify something, without also telling me what is unclear–in fact, it's a waste of everyone's time. Do you know someone with sufficient expertise who could  point me towards specific systems that will benefit my unique circumstances, or perhaps provide a list of a few of the most commonly utilized systems so that i can begin educating myself more thoroughly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tap gesture will give you the coordinates of a tap in the coordinates of the bounds of any view you specify (ie its local coordinate system).  A scrollview does indeed adjust its bounds as you scroll, so in effect the tap is already in your image coordinates assuming your imageview determines your scrollview's content size.  See [locationInView:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624219-locationinview?language=objc)

This should be sufficient to get your coordinates, but it can actually be even simpler than that.  Just make a bunch of buttons of each region that you want to tap with the appropriate icon and give them top left constraints relative to your image view and constant  height width and then drag from each button to your next view controller to create a segues nd you are done.  There is no need to do any math.

Comment: Thanks so much Josh! This is great advice. I appreciate you taking the time to share your expertise.